# Alias creating problem while using CASE query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am using CASE to match certain conditions records in table,
now in where clause I need to use alias of CASES but it is not allowing, the error shows `unknown column monthly_price`.

Here is my query:

```
select 
            (CASE when price > 0 and price < 2000 then (price * 0.05)
            when price > 0 and price <5000 then (price * 1)
            else price
            end)
         as monthly_price,price from qd_posts
         WHERE qd_posts.monthly_price >=0 AND qd_posts.monthly_price <= 5000
```

I am not sure why it is not allowing.

Comment: hey! what are you using for qurey ? qurey builder or Eloquent ? in laravel

Comment: Sorry i am using my custom query builder